# I am unable to making connection to mongodb atlas cluster . i got the MongooseError which as following

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is aongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:10:11) string.

```js
const express = require("express");
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const app = express();

// DB Config
 const db = require('./config/keys').MongoURI;



//Connect to Mongo
mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true ,useUnifiedTopology: true})
.then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected ...."))
.catch(err =>console.log(err));
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

    module.exports ={
      mognoURI:"mongodb+srv://pratham:<pratham>@psm-94d4p.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    };
```

Comment: `require('./config/keys').MongoURI` is undefined. What is `./config/keys`?

Comment: `folder path for URI`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a config folder and inside the config folder, you need to add keys.js file

which looks like this

```
module.exports = {
 MongoURI: 'here goes your connection string which you will get from MongoDB atlas'
 }
```

Comment: I already created keys.js  but its not working .Following is my keys.js file                                                  
 `const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports ={
  mognoURI:"mongodb+srv://pratham:<pratham>@psm-94d4p.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
};`

Comment: If so, then code looks all fine I think there is a Typo you comment as mognoURI and you import MongoURI that's maybe the problem.

Comment: replace <pratham> with pratham (remove angle brackets) hope it works.

Comment: ohhh  Thats working...Thank you so much for helping me